# Rails 3 and crontab - Crontab log is empty

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3.1, cron, ruby-1.9.3, whenever

I implemented gem whenever in my ruby on rails app. This gem generated config file and i have such data there:

**config/schedule.rb**

```
set :output, "/vol/www/apps/logs/cron_log.log"                                #Log for production.
set :my_path, "/vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/current"

every 5.minutes do
  command "cd #{my_path} && bundle exec rake thinking_sphinx:index RAILS_ENV=production && bundle exec rake thinking_sphinx:rebuild RAILS_ENV=production && chmod 777 -R #{my_path}/log"
end
```

So this generates such code in crontab:

```
$ crontab -e

# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: ror_tutorial
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/current && bundle exec rake thinking_sphinx:index RAILS_ENV=production && bundle exec rake thinking_sphinx:rebuild RAILS_ENV=production && chmod 777 -R /vol/www/apps/ror_tutorial/current/log >> /vol/www/apps/logs/cron_log.log 2>&1'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: ror_tutorial
```

Everuthing works but my **cron_log.log** is empty. Why? How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Check out where crond is being started. The logging level may be turned off. [This post here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/cron-log-empty-254494/) explains it fairly well.